# Java How to Wait Until Thread Exits or User Presses Enter

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have a need to exit an application when either a user presses enter, or another thread finishes its work.  The way I accomplished this in the past was the following:

```
// Main
final Worker worker = new Worker();
final Thread workerThread = new Thread(worker::run);
workerThread.start();
try {
    System.in.read();
} catch (final IOException e) {
    // The worker thread finished executing
}

// Worker::run
public void run() {
    ...
    System.in.close();
}
```

This previously seemed to be working just fine, but recently broke after performing some refactoring.  Now, in the call to System.in.close() in the other thread, that thread gets hung indefinitely in FileInputStream::close, in the native method `close0`.  Can anyone explain why this method call is getting hung indefinitely, as if there is a deadlock situation?

I do have a work-around for this, which is the following:

```
// Main.java
private static final Object waitObject = new Object();

private static boolean isRunning = true;

private static void notifyWaitObject() {
    synchronized (waitObject) {
        isRunning = false;
        waitObject.notify();
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // Create a thread to wait until enter is pressed
    final Thread waitThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            // Eat the exception
        } finally {
            notifyWaitObject();
        }
    }, "User Input Thread");
    waitThread.setDaemon(true);
    waitThread.start();

    // Create a worker thread
    final Worker worker = new Worker();
    final Thread workerThread = new Thread(() -> worker.run(Main::notifyWaitObject));
    workerThread.start();

    // Wait until either the worker threads are done, or enter is pressed
    synchronized (waitObject) {
        if (isRunning) waitObject.wait();
    }
}

// Worker.java
public void run(final Runnable exitNotifier) {
    ...
    exitNotifier.run();
}
```

However, the above seems unnecessarily heavy for something that seems like it should be relatively simple.  Does anyone know of a better way to implement this in a thread-safe way?

Comment: @Holger I have updated the question, replacing my "notional" work-around code with the code I actually ended up implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know of any reliable way to stop a thread executing an I/O operation of the old `java.io` streams, afaik that never worked. But since you said, you want to exit the application if either, the worker or the I/O, completed, you can just use:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

es.invokeAny(Arrays.asList(
    () -> { worker.run(); return null; },
    () -> System.in.read() ));

es.shutdown();
System.exit(0);
```

`invokeAny` will return when either job has been completed and even cancel the other with interruption, for the case, it supports it.

Note that since stopping the `System.in.read()` operation doesn’t actually work, there would be a dangling worker thread still executing `System.in.read()` if no console input is provided, but exiting the JVM will terminate all threads anyway.